# Problems with rewriting href values with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url-rewriting

I'm trying to handle urls in plain text.

For now im able to target and rewrite **www.null.com/foo/bar** into an href with the same href and value as the string it self.

*(Thanks Steve Reynolds
http://bit.ly/Xk5Hc)*

```
$("#topcontent p").each(function(){
    var newHTML;
    var stringInput = $(this).html();
    newHTML = replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(stringInput);     
    $(this).html(newHTML).find('a').addClass('highlite');
});

function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
    var exp = /(www[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    return text.replace(exp,"<a href=http://$1>$1</a>");
}
```

---

Now then. Is there a way to modify the anchortag so that the value of it shortens down to .com instead of .com/foo/bar?

```
<a href="http://www.null.com/foo/bar">www.null.com</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var exp = /(www[-A-Z0-9+&@#%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#%=~_|])([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])?/ig;
```

This will match and therefore replace only the section before the first '/' though it will capture the rest as well, leaving you with:

```
<a href="http://www.null.com">www.null.com</a>
```

Edit: Fixed problem with URLs without anything afterwards.  Verified in jsFiddle.net

Comment: But if the link doesn't end with .com/something?

Comment: Works terriffic! Any way this could be applied on emailaddresses aswell?

Comment: `/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})/ig` ought to work as a regular expression for e-mails.  Replace with `"<a href=mailto:$1>$1</a>"`.  Borrowed from http://www.zparacha.com/validate-email-address-using-javascript-regular-expression/ which explains the logic behind the regular expression (removed $ and ^).

Answer (score 0):

it is easier if you just do a function to return just the cleaned html, so:

```
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
    var exp = /(www[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    return text.replace(exp,"$1");
}
```

and then just add the href and html separate:

```
href = replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(stringInput);
var link = $(document.createElement('a')).attr('href', 'http://'+href)
              .addClass('highlite')
              .html(href.replace(/\/[^.]+$/gi, ''));
$(this).html(link);
```

that will just create a new link object, add the correct href you return with your function and then replaces all ending non-dot characters with '' (in your case this will always be the /foo/bar)

Also, this is a lot better than your previous example because it is less javascript intensive (you don't have to find the 'a' again and then modify its properties, you just create one with those properties from the start)

Comment: So... How would I stuff this into my code? Tried a few variants, but just ended up with making the whole paragraph into a link

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

Regex: `a href=["']*http:\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9+&@#%=~_|.]+)`

http://www.rubular.com/r/6UNlh52T86

Comment: As for that example, I dont think it does (or I dont know even if it could, I guess). I havn't got any hrefs to start with. Just trying to filter out what looks like links from a plain textstring and enclosing those pieces of text in anchors.

Comment: I totally missed the "plain text" part of your initial question. My bad, sorry. Trying some other things now.